# SQL Creating Table Dependencies

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I've been stuck at creating tables.

Here is the code I am stuck at how to make the code work in `loan_type` to write office worker or non office worker

```
create table loaner 
(
   loan_id number(5) primary key,
   loan_type VARCHAR2 (16),
   loan_start_date date,
   loan_end_date date,
)

create table office_worker 
(
   worker_id number(5) primary_key,
   loan_id number(5) references loaner(loan_id),
   worker_name varchar2(50)
)

create table nonoffice_worker 
(
   nonworker_id number(5) primary_key,
   loan_id number(5) references loaner(loan_id),
   nonworker_name varchar2(50)
);

commit;
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: And would it not be better to have all workers in 1 table and just have a column that is called `is_office`

Comment: nope, not getting error, loan type for office workers and non office workers have different type of loans, so what i require is that how to put check statement whether the loaner type is office worker or non office worker

Comment: @Matt sorry forgot to tag you guys

Comment: are they only differences between the workers the loan type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a constrain to check that with the existing table structures.  A common way to do it is like this:

```
create table loaner (
loan_id number(5) primary key,
loan_type VARCHAR2 (16),
loan_start_date date,
loan_end_date date,
constraint loaner_uk unique (loan_id, loan_type)
);

create table office_worker (
worker_id number(5) primary_key,
loan_id number(5),
loan_type VARCHAR2 (16),
worker_name varchar2(50),
constraint office_worker_loaner_fk foreeign key (loan_id, loan_type) references loaner (loan_id, loan_type),
constraint office_worker_loan_type_chk check (loan_type = 'OFFICE')
);

create table nonoffice_worker (
nonworker_id number(5) primary_key,
loan_id number(5),
loan_type VARCHAR2 (16),
nonworker_name varchar2(50),
constraint nonoffice_worker_loaner_fk foreeign key (loan_id, loan_type) references loaner (loan_id, loan_type),
constraint nonoffice_worker_loan_type_chk check (loan_type = 'NONOFFICE')
);
```

That is:

1. Create a redundant UNIQUE constraint in (load_id, loan_type) in the first table.
2. Add loan_type to the subtype tables and base the foreign key on (loan_id, loan_type).
3. Add a check constraint to each subtype table to ensure the correct loan_type is used.

Comment: this seems to be so complicated, thanks on the help will work on it

Comment: This is a valid solution. I also add check constraint option, in case his table have rigth values on column loan_type

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a check constraint to your table, but you must check that column loan_type only contains desired values(`office worker` or `non office worker`), else this won't work:

```
alter table loaner add (CONSTRAINT chk_loan_type CHECK 
(loan_type='office worker' or loan_type='non office worker'));
```